# Issue java gradle "Could not find org.jnetpcap:jnetpcap:1.4.1."

Tags: java, gradle

for a personal project I would like to use this git project: https://github.com/ahlashkari/CICFlowMeter or I have an issue which is:

```
type Jar
type JavaExec
:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not find org.jnetpcap:jnetpcap:1.4.1.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/root/.m2/repository/org/jnetpcap/jnetpcap/1.4.1/jnetpcap-1.4.1.pom
      file:/root/.m2/repository/org/jnetpcap/jnetpcap/1.4.1/jnetpcap-1.4.1.jar
      https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jnetpcap/jnetpcap/1.4.1/jnetpcap-1.4.1.pom
      https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jnetpcap/jnetpcap/1.4.1/jnetpcap-1.4.1.jar
      https://clojars.org/repo/org/jnetpcap/jnetpcap/1.4.1/jnetpcap-1.4.1.pom
      https://clojars.org/repo/org/jnetpcap/jnetpcap/1.4.1/jnetpcap-1.4.1.jar
  Required by:
      project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

I did what the git ask which is:

```
//linux :at the pathtoproject/jnetpcap/linux/jnetpcap-1.4.r1425
//windows: at the pathtoproject/jnetpcap/win/jnetpcap-1.4.r1425
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=jnetpcap.jar -DgroupId=org.jnetpcap -DartifactId=jnetpcap -Dversion=1.4.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

then

```
//linux:
$ sudo bash
$ gradle execute

//windows:
$ gradlew execute
```

(I am on Fedora)

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

After few searchs, here is how I solved this issue:

I opened build.gradle and at line 20 I replaced:

```
compile group: 'org.jnetpcap', name: 'jnetpcap', version:'1.4.1'
```

by

```
compile group: 'jnetpcap', name: 'jnetpcap', version:'1.4.r1425-1g'
```

That's it !